# Service not available, closing transmission channel. The server response was: 4.4.2 Timeout while waiting for command

Tags: asp.net, smtp

I'm trying to send a message and we sometime get this error :
`Service not available, closing transmission channel. The server response was: 4.4.2 Timeout while waiting for command.`

Anyone know what to do with this? Because it only happens "sometime" and apperently, for no specific reason.

I saw many article saying :
`442 The server started to deliver the message but then the connection was broke` (Source : http://www.sorkincomputer.net/SMTP%20errors.htm)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is typically a server side (the SMTP server you're delivering to) error or a network connectivity error.  There isn't anything you can do about it via your code, you would need to get the related IT staff involved to figure out why your connection is getting closed or interrupted.

Comment: Thanks you Coding Gorilla! It prevents us to search for hour about something we have no control!